# Applying a pandas filter to a dataframe gives a dataframe full of NaN's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I can't figure out why is this happening. I'm trying to apply a pandas filter to a bigger df composed by 29k rows and 64 columns. However, i have managed to reproduce the same error on a toy df i will use here for explanatory purposes.

Imagine you have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'contr': [1,2,3,4,5], 'type': [1356, 89, 134, 79, 117], 'total': [582747.2, 267492.4, 264894.6, -12727438.3, 7362748.6]})



contr   type    total   
    1   1356    582747.2    
    2     89    267492.4    
    3    134    264894.6    
    4     79   -127438.3    
    5    117    7362748.6
```

Then you scale it using standard scaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns = [df.columns])
```

Now let's add a column to filter by:

```
labels = [1,2,3,4,5]
df_scaled['labels'] = labels
```

If i apply these filters:

```
labels1 = df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 1]
labels2 = df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 2]
labels3 = df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 3]
labels4 = df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 4]
```

This is what i'm getting:

```
labels1

Out[1]:     

contr   type    total   labels
  NaN    NaN      NaN      1.0
  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
  NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

If i apply the same filter to the original df:

```
labels1 = df[df['labels'] == 1]
labels2 = df[df['labels'] == 2]
labels3 = df[df['labels'] == 3]
labels4 = df[df['labels'] == 4]
```

The results look as expected:

labels1

Out[2]:

```
contr   type    total   labels
    1   1356 582747.2    1

labels2

Out [3]: 

contr   type    total   labels
    2     89 267492.4        2
```

And so on for the rest of filters.

I just can't figure out why this strange behavior is happening, but it seems that pandas filtering fails when applied to a scaled dataframe.

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how to avoid it?? I'm totally lost here.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Btw, this is a nice formulated question.

Comment: @NunodeSousa Thank you!! :)

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, `df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 1]` gives a dataframe with one row (as expected) on Pandas 0.19.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
labels1 = df_scaled[(df_scaled['labels'] == 1).values]
labels2 = df_scaled[(df_scaled['labels'] == 2).values]
labels3 = df_scaled[(df_scaled['labels'] == 3).values]
labels4 = df_scaled[(df_scaled['labels'] == 4).values]
```

For some reason (that I don't know why) the filter that you are applying is not being converted into a Series.

EDIT 1:

The reason for this is because the labels column is a MultiIndex and not a simple column of the dataframe. You can see this by making `df_scaled.columns`.

If you change the column names `df_scaled.columns = ['contr', 'total', 'type', 'labels']`, then the `df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 1]` will work.

EDIT 2:

If you change the line:

```
 df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns = [df.columns])
```

to

```
 df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns = df.columns)
```

You have your problem solved.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer!! Could add some explanation about why this behavior is happening please?? it would be pretty useful for the sake of understanding&learning

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem on Pandas v0.19.2: `df_scaled[df_scaled['labels'] == 1]` gives a dataframe of one row as expected. Run your code in a new session with code *exactly* as you have defined in the question and see if you can replicate.

In addition, `df[df['labels'] == 1]` should *never* work, because you never defined `df['labels']` in your code.

However, you should try and avoid creating a variable number of variables, here you can use `groupby`:

```
dfs = df_scaled.groupby('labels')
```

Then use `dfs.get_group(1)`, `dfs.get_group(2)`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thank your for your answer. I didn't define `df[df['labels'] == 1]` in the question but i did in my computer, actually, i forgot to add that part to the code in question but it sounds logic, since i'm claiming not to be able to apply the same filters in the 2 dataframes. 

Regarding my pandas version, i'm using pandas 0.23. NunodeSousa's answer solved the problem though, but thank you for your apport :)